# QuTS hero TVS-h1688X: how to use all 6 NICs?

Tags: networking, qnap

I have a NAS, "QuTS hero TVS-h1688X", which appears to have 6 NICs; is there any way to use all of them, eg. for some form of multi-pathing for faster network access?

Answer (score 1):

The NAS appears to support link aggregation using LACP (aka 802.3ad). If you also have an Ethernet switch that supports LACP, you can bond 2 or 4 connections  into a single "kinda 2×" or "kinda 4×" connection. But note that in this mode, each TCP connection or UDP flow will still go through one physical NIC only.

Note that this assignment is done by hashing the packet header (and it's also why the number of links should preferably be a power of two – e.g. 2, 4, 8, but usually not 3 or 6). Both the NAS and the switch will have a "hashing policy" setting to determine whether flows are assigned to physical interface by TCP port (layer4), or just by IP address (layer3), or only by MAC address (layer2). (So in Layer3 hashing mode, for example, all packets sent to the same client will go through the same NIC and it will still get 1× speed.)

Many devices only offer L3/L2 modes. This means that only having at minimum 4 separate client devices would actually take full advantage of 4-way LACP – and even then, there's a chance that several clients get hashed to the same physical interface.